# Value restriction in F#

Tags: f#, value-restriction

I've got an F# assignment where I am trying to compute the transpose of a matrix. Simple enough, but I keep getting a value restriction error and I cannot figure out why. I consulted many of the VR error questions that are out there, but I'm still in the dark. Here's my code:

```
let transpose = function
    | [xs ; ys] -> 
                let rec transpose_helper = function
                    | [],[] -> []
                    | x::xs , y::ys -> [x;y] :: transpose_helper (xs,ys)
                    | _ -> failwith "The matrix is not a square matrix"
                transpose_helper(xs,ys)
    | _ -> failwith "Incorrectly formatted input"

transpose ([[1;2;3];[2;3;4]]);;
```

I assume the error is in part due to the empty list, but nothing I do seems to help. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This following version of the code, works. Could anyone explain *why*?

```
let transpose zs =
    match zs with 
    | [xs;ys] -> 
                let rec transpose_helper (xs, ys) = 
                    match (xs,ys) with
                    | ([],[]) -> []
                    | (x::xs , y::ys) -> [x;y] :: transpose_helper (xs,ys)
                    | _ -> failwith "The matrix is not a square matrix"
                transpose_helper(xs,ys)
    | _ -> failwith "Incorrectly formatted input"

transpose ([[1;2;3];[2;3;4]]);;

val transpose : zs:'a list list -> 'a list list
val it : int list list = [[1; 2]; [2; 3]; [3; 4]]
```

However, the compiler still complains that the transpose call above should have a unit type unless I bind it using lets. Could anyone please clarify what is going on here?

Comment: Which school is giving you an assignment in F#, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you originally wrote this `let rec transpose zs = match zs with ...` and later changed it to use `function` instead, which removes the need for the explicit argument. Since `zs` is still there your function accepts two args which means you're only partially applying it. Since `zs` is unused its type is unknown making your partially applied function return a generic function *value* (value restriction). Remove `zs` and all is well.

Comment: My apologies for the late comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to solve the issue and the value restriction error remains. I've made the initial function non-recursive as I saw that it was not necessary, as well. Casting it (perhaps to an int list list) does not seem to work, either.

Comment: I've added a working version of the code with uses the match ... with ... pattern, but I am unsure of *why* it works in the first place when I still get a warning about types. I would greatly appreciate it if you could clarify!

Comment: After editing, both your `transpose` functions are equivalent and work. The latest error can be fixed by binding the result using `let` or piping to ignore (`|> ignore`).